# Prevent navbar for collapsing

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am designing a side navbar for my website. Its working fine till medium screen size but when screen size is reduced (<768px) Its getting all messy.
Here is my HTML and CSS code

```css
.main .row {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}
/*Remove rounded coners*/

nav.sidebar.navbar {
  border-radius: 0px;
}
nav.sidebar,
.main {
  -webkit-transition: margin 200ms ease-out;
  -moz-transition: margin 200ms ease-out;
  -o-transition: margin 200ms ease-out;
  transition: margin 200ms ease-out;
}
/* .....NavBar: Icon only with coloring/layout.....*/

/*Allow main to be next to Nav*/

.main {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: 40px;
  float: right;
}
/*lets nav bar to be showed on mouseover*/

nav.sidebar:hover + .main {
  margin-left: 200px;
}
/*Center Brand*/

nav.sidebar.navbar.sidebar>.container .navbar-brand,
.navbar>.container-fluid .navbar-brand {
  margin-left: 0px;
}
/*Center Brand*/

nav.sidebar .navbar-brand,
nav.sidebar .navbar-header {
  text-align: center;
  width: auto;
  margin-left: 0px;
}
/*Center Icons*/

nav.sidebar a {
  padding-right: 13px;
}
/*adds border top to first nav box */

nav.sidebar .navbar-nav > li:first-child {
  border-top: 1px #e5e5e5 solid;
}
.nav-collapse,
.nav-collapse.collapse {
  overflow: visible;
}
.navbar .btn-navbar {
  display: none;
}
/*adds border to bottom nav boxes*/

nav.sidebar .navbar-nav > li {
  border-bottom: 1px #e5e5e5 solid;
}
/* Colors/style dropdown box*/

nav.sidebar .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu {
  position: static;
  float: none;
  width: auto;
  margin-top: 0;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}
/*allows nav box to use 100% width*/

nav.sidebar,
nav.sidebar .container-fluid {
  padding: 0 0px 0 0px;
}
/*colors dropdown box text */

.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu>li>a {
  color: #777;
}
/*gives sidebar width/height*/

nav.sidebar {
  width: 200px;
  height: inherit;
  margin-left: -160px;
  float: left;
  z-index: 8000;
}
/*give sidebar 100% width;*/

nav.sidebar li {
  width: 100%;
}
/* Move nav to full on mouse over*/

nav.sidebar:hover {
  margin-left: 0px;
}
/* .....NavBar: Fully showing nav bar..... */

nav.sidebar .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu>li>a:hover,
nav.sidebar .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu>li>a:focus {
  color: #CCC;
  background-color: transparent;
}
nav:hover .forAnimate {
  opacity: 1;
}
section {
  padding-left: 15px;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse sidebar" role="navigation">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home<span style="font-size:16px;" class="pull-right glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span></a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Profile<span style="font-size:16px;" class="pull-right glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span></a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Messages<span style="font-size:16px;" class="pull-right glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Settings <span class="caret"></span><span style="font-size:16px;" class="pull-right hidden-xs showopacity glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu forAnimate" role="menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>
            </li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>
            </li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Home<span style="font-size:16px;" class="pull-right  showopacity glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span></a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Profile<span style="font-size:16px;" class="pull-right  showopacity glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span></a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Messages<span style="font-size:16px;" class="pull-right showopacity glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Settings <span class="caret"></span><span style="font-size:16px;" class="pull-right hidden-xs showopacity glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu forAnimate" role="menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>
            </li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>
            </li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
<div class="main">
  <!-- Content Here -->
</div>
```

Can someone suggest any solution?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: For me this code is messy all the time, no matter screen size. That said, when using float, a clearfix is normally needed to make parent size with content

Comment: remove margin on `navbar-nav` class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove the margin from `.navbar-nav` class.

```
.navbar-nav{
  margin:0;
}
```

also note that the gear icon is hidden until 767px.
codepen [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oYjMGM)